# Websocket doesn't work with handleActionWithIdentifier ( UILocalNotification )

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, uilocalnotification, pushkit

In my app, i am using [pushkit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/PushKit_Framework/) for silent push notification as app in related to VOIP.

Once i get payload `didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload`, i keep invoke websocket connection and schedule UILocalNotification with category and identifier like **"Accept"** and **"Reject"** button on notification.

"Reject" button works with background mode ( which does not invoke app ) and interact with websocket messages.

This stuff works fine when app is in background mode, once i terminate app ( kill app ), then websocket from handleActionWithIdentifier doesn't work.

> Note -  Websocket connection get closed while terminated app, but i
>   keep it invoke again when getting silent push kit notification

Does anybody idea for above problem ?

Comment: y u not use local notification for this stuff

Comment: @Hasya Here is best tutorial for pushkit [PUSHKIT FOR IOS VOIP](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/ios8-apps-and-pushkit)

Comment: @sanandiyavipul - Read question first, local notification is already in use.

Comment: @NimitParekh - Push notification is already implemented, problem is with handleActionWithIdentifier ( UILocalNotification ) which doesn't work with websocket object.